# I am unable to install programs after 12.04 upgrade and attempt to install Libreoffice

Tags: upgrade, package-management, libreoffice

I tried to install Libreoffice on Ubuntu 12.04 (after an upgrade), and now I can't install, ugrade, anything in any form.  When I go to the Software center, I get a message that I need to repair the package catalog before I can install anything.  But the repair fails because of Libreoffice files.

When I try to run sudo apt-get -f install, or sudo apt-get upgrade, or anything else, those libreoffice files prevent any solution.

I tried:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

But that didn't help either.

Here is the output of both the install and repair attempts: http://pastebin.com/A8ztjDTR

> Unpacking libreoffice-common (from .../libreoffice-common_1%3a3.5.2-2ubuntu1_all.deb) ...
>   dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a3.5.2-2ubuntu1_all.deb (--unpack):
>    trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/soffice', which is also in package openoffice.org-debian-menus 3.3-9556
>   No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please copy.paste the output of above command to pastebin and provide link to us :)

Comment: Here is the output of both the install and repair attempts:
http://pastebin.com/A8ztjDTR

Answer (score 2):

The `openoffice.org-debian-menus` is the cause of your problems. This should sort it:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a3.5.2-2ubuntu1_all.deb
```

Then you should be able to continue with your upgrade.

Comment: I used aptitude to remove all traces of Libreoffice, and now I can start over.  I suppose that your solution would have worked better.  Thanks.